# Горизонтальный скроллинг

Tags: html, css

Необходимо было реализовать прижатие футера у низу страницы. Нашел замечательный [способ](http://www.web-in.ru/kak-prizhat-footer-k-nizu-stranicy) (использовал второй).

Однако, при довольно малой ширине окна браузера не появляется горизонтальный скроллинг.

Как это можно исправить?

Comment: Все в порядке. Вот проверьте: http://cssdesk.com/qfX7v
Логика такая. Нижний элемент плавающий, он будет перекрывать элемент контента (в примере section), и потому снизу добавляем отступ в висоту подвала (footer).

Comment: Если самому пока сложно одолеть такую верстку, то можно [воспользоваться онлайн генератором](http://csstemplater.com/)

Comment: @Gordio, нет, не все в порядке. Попробуй уменьшить ширину окна и увидишь, что текст обрезается.

Comment: Ах. Так это дело 5 минут. Для html и или body ставим   min-width: 600px;

Comment: Убрал "Яндекс элементы" со страницы - проблемы больше нет.

Спасибо за помощь!

Answer (score 1):

```
#footer{
    max-height: 100%; //максимальная ширина
    overflow-x: scroll; //прокрутка у блока если контент не поместился 
}
```

Comment: @Rules, так ведь не надо обрезать.

Comment: А что надо делать если размер футера не вмещяется по ширине в окно браузера?

Comment: @Rules, олжен появиться горизонтальный скроллинг как минимум

Comment: А, тогда изменил ответ...
P.S
 
>должен появиться горизонтальный скроллинг как минимум

а
 
>как максимум

 что?

Comment: Да, спасибо, уже разобрался.
P.S. В новом ответе неверный комментарий к коду.
P.S.S. В идеале должен получиться Responsive Web Design.

Comment: Да всё исправил! Что за

>Responsive Web Design

Реагирующий Веб Дизайн? Что это (извините если глупый вопрос но может я смогу в достижении этого помочь)?

Comment: @Rules, это уже отдельная (намного более сложная) тема.